# Finding the minimum value of a nested list and its index

Tags: python, list, min

I have a nested list that contains both None elements and integers. It looks pretty much like this:

```
aList = [[None, 8.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [9.0], [5.0, None, 4.0]]
```

None elements don't follow any particular pattern and therefore can be found at any position inside the list. I'd like to obtain two things:

1. The minimum value (*minimum*) among all integers.
2. The indexes that define completely the position of this minimum value. In other words, those two numbers ( *i, j* ) that satisfy:

   ```
   aList[i][j] = minimum
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
aList = [[None, 8.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [9.0], [5.0, None, 4.0]]

minimum = sys.maxsize
i_min, j_min = 0, 0

for i, a in enumerate(aList):
    for j, b in enumerate(a):
        if b and b < minimum:
            i_min, j_min, minimum = i, j, b

print(minimum, i_min, j_min)
# 1.0 0 2
print(aList[i_min][j_min] == minimum)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
import sys

aList = [[None, 8.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [9.0], [5.0, None, 4.0]]
mininum = sys.maxsize

for j, ele in enumerate(aList):
    cur_min = min(float(i) for i in ele if i is not None)
    if cur_min < mininum:
        minimum = cur_min
        pos_index = ele.index(minimum)
        list_index = j

print(aList[list_index][pos_index])
```